# View not rendered in a storybased ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode-storyboard

I have a ViewController which is mapped to a scene on storyboard. And it is initialized by a segue.

However, view that is initialized and customized in onViewLoad() method in ViewController is not rendered in ViewController. My ViewController is rendered as a blank scene on iphone simulator.

Should View in the viewcontroller be mapped to some attribute on storyboard to render my view in the viewcontroller?

Comment: Some code of your view's initialization would help.

Comment: What do you mean by "it is initialized by a segue"? What type of segue is it? What is the initial view controller of your storyboard?

Comment: Do you want to use ```IB_DESIGNABLE```, it works on subclass of UIView, not UIViewController.